# Find the order of a factor group $G/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $g\in G$. Define a map $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$ when $\phi(x)=g^{-1}xg$. Let $K$ be the kernel of homomorphism $\phi$. Find the order of the factor group $G/K$.

I start to define $\phi$

Let $ϕ(x) = gxg^{−1}$ for all $x ∈ G$. Clearly $ϕ$ maps $G$ into $G$. First we will show $ϕ$ is a homomorphism. The homorphism condition holds for $ϕ$ because

$ϕ(xy) = g(xy)g^{−1} = gxyg^{−1} = gx(g^{−1}g)yg^{−1}=(gxg^{−1})(gyg^{−1})= ϕ(x)ϕ(y)$.

Next, $ϕ$ is injective, for if $ϕ(x) = ϕ(y)$ then $gxg^{−1} = gyg^{−1}$, so by multiplying this equation of the left of $g^{−1}$ and on the right by $g$ we get $g^{−1}(gxg^{−1})g = g^{−1}(gyg^{−1})g$, hence $(g^{−1}g)x(g^{−1}g) = (g^{−1}g) y(g^{−1}g)$, hence $x = y$. Finally, $ϕ$ is surjective because if $x ∈ G$ then $ϕ(y) = x$ where $y = g^{−1}xg$, since $ϕ(y) =ϕ(g^{−1}xg) = g(g^{−1}xg)g^{−1} = x$.

Am I fine in my definition?? Next:

Isomorphisms preserve order, so $|x| = |ϕ(x)| = |gxg^{−1}|$ for all $x ∈ G$. An
isomorphism is a bijection, and bijections preserve cardinality of sets, so for any subset $A ⊆ G, |A| = |gAg^{−1}|$.

Now how can I find the order of a factor group $G/K$??

Comment: For  $\;\phi\;$ to make any sense, I think, it must be that $\;G'\le G\;$ , or at least both $\;G,G'\;$ are contained in one group. If it is the first option then $\;\phi\;$ is pretty boring since $\;G\;$ is given abelian: it is the identity map. So, what is missing here??

Comment: As it stands, ϕ is the identity map on an abelian group $G$, $K = \{e\}$, and $G/K \cong G$, which means it has the same order as $G$. I second Joanpemo's hunch that this might not be the full question.

Comment: Another hint that something might be missing is the omission of any finiteness assumption.  The problem could be worked in some generality, but asking to "find the order" of a quotient almost mandates some information about the size of the original group $G$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know
$$\frac{G}{ker\,\Phi}\cong \operatorname{Im}\,(\Phi )$$
let $x\in G$. It is clear $\Phi (gx{{g}^{-1}})=x$ then $G\subseteq G'$. On the other hand $\Phi$ is one to one so $G=G'$.

$\Phi$ is surjective, then
$$\frac{G}{K}\cong G$$
Edit

Comment: With all due respect I don't think this makes any sense, leave alone to answer the question, which so far is hard to tell what exactly it is.

Comment: @ Joanpemo is my solution wrong?

Comment: @Be Thank you. I think it is *not even* wrong: for example, how can you say $\;\phi\;$ is surjective if we still can't tell what's the relation between $\;G, G'\;$ ?? We could certainly guess that $\;G'\;$ is the commutator subgroup of $\;G\;$ , yet it is given $\;G\;$ is abelian so $\;G'=1\;$ , and then the whole exercise is boringly trivial. It is true that if $\;G,\,G'\;$ are contained in a bigger *abelian* group then $\;\phi\;$ is trivial so $\;\ker\phi=1\;$ and then what you wrote is true, but *how can we know what the asker meant if he hasn't yet addressed the doubts in the comments* ?

Comment: My teacher did not give me more information about this problem, then applying First isomorphism theorem we know that $G/ker \phi = G'$, but $\phi$ is bijective then $G$ have the same elements of $G'$ then $|G/ker \phi |=|G'|=|G|$????